# Apache Camel / xpath operation result detection

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

Given a Camel route that is supposed to extract some inner parts of an XML message, create a new message from it then pass it on.

```
 from(SUB_EXTRACT_XML)
   .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
   .setBody().xpath("//mmsg:MyMessage/mmsg:AnyPayload/*", namespaces) 
   .setBody().simple("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n${in.body}")
   .to(...)
```

For correct input messages like this (an "embedded" xml message is inside  defined in schema by xs:any), it's working since the message is what I expect it to be:

```
<mmsg:MyMessage>
  <mmsg:RandomTags/>
   ...
   <mmsg:AnyPayload> <!-- xs:any in xsd -->
     <some><xml/><here/></some>
   </mmsg:AnyPayload>
</mmsg:MyMessage>
```

Given there is some issues with the XML message, such as the mmsg:AnyPayload tag is missing, so that the XPATH can't do its job:

```
<mmsg:MyMessage>
  <mmsg:RandomTags/>
   ...
   <some><xml/><here/></some>
</mmsg:MyMessage>
```

The XPATH will fail to extract the data and the entire XML message (including mmsg:MyMessage) is passed on, which is not intended. I rather throw some exception at this stage.

**Question:**

Is there a way to check if the xpath expression actually found the element refered to later in the route or if it failed to extract the given element(s)?

I know I could have done some schema validation of the message before and reject rubbish messages, but are there any way to see if a XPath expression fails?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: 2.9.2 in the specific case. We could possibly upgrade to 2.10.1 if it helps out here.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the `choice()` DSL in the route like this:

```
 from(SUB_EXTRACT_XML)
   .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
   .choice()
        .when(xpath("//mmsg:MyMessage/mmsg:AnyPayload", namespaces))
            .setHeader("Status", "OK") // just for another example how to transmit some variable between two routes 
            .setBody().simple("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n${in.body}")
            .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "LoggerName", "Error message; Stop the processing")
            .stop()
        .endChoice()
    .end()
   // Just to show the headers are following the route... 
   .to("DIRECT_GO_FORWARD"); 



 from("DIRECT_GO_FORWARD")
   .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
   .choice()
        .when(header("Status").isEqualTo("OK"))
            .bean(new SampleProcessor())

        ...
    .end()
    ...
    .to("...");
```

the second route is just there to show you can use the header set in the first route (and the body too).